# Nest a select statement inside array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json())) in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to understand why this works:

```
select
    array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(positions_table)))
from (
    select
        sum(start_month),
        function_id,
        profile_id
    from positions as subquery
    group by function_id, profile_id
) as positions_table
```

But this does not:

```
select
    profiles.id,
    (array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(
        select
            sum(start_month),
            function_id,
            profile_id
        from positions as subquery
        group by function_id, profile_id
    ))))
from profiles
```

It seems like I'm not allowed to put the `select...` statement inside `array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json()))` and that it needs to reference a table instead.

But I'm suspicious I might be missing something.

The error is `syntax error near select`.

Comment: FYI: instead of doing 3 data conversions (json, array, json) you should use `jsonb_agg()` instead for your wishful result [see more](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html). Also, `row_to_json` expects `record` as input, subquery is not a record it is set of records, so you can't expect function that's purpose is to convert 1 single row to json to convert N rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fix your syntax error by wrapping your sub-select in brackets, but then you'd see your second error; postgres would report:

> subquery must return only one column

If you fixed *that* error you'd see:

> column "profiles.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

...which is getting closer to the real cause of your problem. Adding `GROUP BY id` will get postgres to report the root cause:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

The function `row_to_json` is expecting a single row.

To aggregate your json summaries by profile id you'll have to perform a join.

```
SELECT
  pr.id,
  array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(positions_table.*)))
FROM profiles pr JOIN (
  SELECT sum(start_month), function_id, profile_id
  FROM positions
  GROUP BY function_id, profile_id
) positions_table ON positions_table.profile_id = pr.id
GROUP BY pr.id
```

(You can drop the `.*` from `positions_table.*`, I just added it for clarity).